# PHP string comparison gives wrong output:

Tags: php, string, comparison

I am using this code for comparing string values in a method, which work perfectly. But for some value it gives wrong value, for example below values:

Code:

```
$string1 = "65";
$string2 = "5-fold";
$result = strcasecmp($string1, $string2);

switch ($result) {
    case -1: print "65 comes before 5-fold"; break;
    case 0: print "65 and 5-fold are the same"; break;
    case 1: print "65 comes after 5-fold"; break;
}
```

Output:

```
65 comes after 5-fold
```

I use this code for sorted array list, which sort them like ( 65 comes before 5-fold ). may be this output of because the " - " or something else i don't know. Do you have any idea about this.....

Below code Sort the multi-dimensional array:

```
       foreach($index_terms as $c=>$key) {
            $sort_id[] = $key['id'];
            $sort_term[] = $key['term'];
            $sort_freq[] = $key['freq'];
        }

        array_multisort($sort_term, SORT_ASC, $index_terms);
```

Comment: 6 comes after 5, no? so `65` should come after `5-fold`.

Comment: yes you are right, but what i mean is to consider "5-fold" as a whole string....like what php function array_multisort() sort them.....

Comment: What is in $sort_term and $index_terms?

Comment: $index_terms is actually the big index terms array....and the sor_term is sorted terms array created for the sorting of big index terms array....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing `65` to `5-fold`.  It returns -1 if `65` is less than `5-fold` and 1 if `65` is greater than `5-fold`.

65 is greater than 5-fold... I don't see the problem?

What is 5-fold supposed to be that you want 65 to come before it?

Comment: yes: because i sorted the list already on "array_multisort()" which place 65 before 5-fold...

Comment: Show us the code that puts 65 before 5-fold, because I don't think we're understanding. `array_multisort()` can sort based off the ordering of another array and may not ever even be comparing 65 to 5-fold. I think the issue may be a misunderstanding of `array_multisort()`?

Comment: I have updated my question, for the array_multisort() method.

Comment: Have you tried `array_multisort($sort_term, SORT_ASC, $index_terms, SORT_ASC);`?

Answer (score 0):

**Code :**

```
<?php
    $string1 = "65";
    $string2 = "5-fold";
    $result = strcasecmp($string1, $string2);

    echo $result;
?>
```

**Output :**

> 1

---

***Hint :** There's nothing wrong with your output. `1` means the second operand is greater, `-1` means the first operand is greater.*

Comment: I know it return 1, but i sorted the list on array_multisort() which place the 65 before 5-fold in the list...now i want a comparison which do work like array_multisort().....

Answer (score 0):

try to use [Intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

strcasecmp compare the binary value of your string

```
$string1 = intVal("65"); 
$string2 = intVal("5-fold");  
$result = strcasecmp($string1, $string2);

switch ($result) {
    case -1: print "65 comes before 5-fold"; break;
    case 0: print "65 and 5-fold are the same"; break;
    case 1: print "65 comes after 5-fold"; break; }
```